# Where did this YUV420P to RGB shader conversion come from?

Tags: image-processing, opengl, matrix, video, glsl

I'm trying to understand these calculations for YUV420P to RGB conversion on an OpenGL fragment shader. On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV there are lots of calculations but none of them look like the one below. Why take `0.0625` and `0.5` and `0.5` in the first part? And where did the second part come from?

```
yuv.r = texture(tex_y, TexCoord).r - 0.0625;
yuv.g = texture(tex_u, TexCoord).r - 0.5;
yuv.b = texture(tex_v, TexCoord).r - 0.5;

rgba.r = yuv.r + 1.596 * yuv.b
rgba.g = yuv.r - 0.813 * yuv.b - 0.391 * yuv.g;
rgba.b = yuv.r + 2.018 * yuv.g;
```

It may be an special color conversion for some specific YUV color scheme but I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why take [...] 0.5 and 0.5 in the first part?

*U* and *V* are stored in the green and blue color channel of the texture. The values in the color channels are stored in the range [0.0, 1.0]. For the computations the values have to be in mapped to the range [-0.5, 0.5]:

```c
yuv.g = texture(tex_u, TexCoord).r - 0.5;
yuv.b = texture(tex_v, TexCoord).r - 0.5;
```

Subtracting `0.0625` from the red color channel is just an optimization. Thus, It does not have to be subtracted separately in each expression later.

The algorithm is the same as in [How to convert RGB -> YUV -> RGB (both ways)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892346/how-to-convert-rgb-yuv-rgb-both-ways) or various books.

Comment: I just didn't get the `1.164*Y` on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17934865/6655884. There's none on mine (`yuv.r`)

Comment: @LucasZanella There are different formulas. See [Color Conversion](https://web.archive.org/web/20180423091842/http://www.equasys.de/colorconversion.html). There is not the one and only transformation the color space can be interpreted differently.